# Can not get XML attribute value using PHP

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, nodes, xmlnode

```
<Pages TotalPages="56" ProductCode="Headline" PubDate="2012-01-31" PubVersion="0" PubSubVersion="0" PageWidth="1622" PageHeight="1902">
              <Page PageNo="1" PageName="" PageType="" Section="Section" ThumbnailPath="http://203.80.1.28/FlippingBook/Dev/Frontend/demo/Headline/2012/12/20/0/0/A/Content/1/Pv001.png" ImagePath="http://203.80.1.28/FlippingBook/Dev/Frontend/demo/Headline/2012/12/20/0/0/A/Content/1/Pg001_142_p.jpg" OverlayFullPath="http://203.80.1.28/FlippingBook/Dev/Frontend/demo/Headline/2012/12/20/0/0/A/Content/1/Pg001_142_t.png" PreviewPath="http://203.80.1.28/FlippingBook/Dev/Frontend/demo/Headline/2012/12/20/0/0/A/Content/1/Pg001.png" IsPreview="true" ImageHeight="1902" ImageWidth="1622" WithResource="true" /> 
              <Page PageNo="2" PageName="" PageType="" Section="Section" ThumbnailPath="http://203.80.1.28/FlippingBook/Dev/Frontend/demo/Headline/2012/12/20/0/0/A/Content/2/Pv002.png" ImagePath="http://203.80.1.28/FlippingBook/Dev/Frontend/demo/Headline/2012/12/20/0/0/A/Content/2/Pg002_142_p.jpg" OverlayFullPath="http://203.80.1.28/FlippingBook/Dev/Frontend/demo/Headline/2012/12/20/0/0/A/Content/2/Pg002_142_t.png" PreviewPath="http://203.80.1.28/FlippingBook/Dev/Frontend/demo/Headline/2012/12/20/0/0/A/Content/2/Pg002.png" IsPreview="true" ImageHeight="1902" ImageWidth="1622" WithResource="true" /> 
</Pages>
```

**PHP:**

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($dir) 
       or die("Error: Cannot create object");
//$fileList = array();

foreach($xml->children() as $Pages){
    foreach($Pages->children() as $Page => $page){
    $fileLink = $page['ThumbnailPath'];
    echo $fileLink;
    }
}
```

What I am going to get is the ThumbnailPath from node "Page" , I loop through Pages and page but it turn out gets nothing, how to fix this problem ? Thanks

Comment: Can you show me what is `$dir` ?

Comment: sure, $dir is the path of xml file , and it is exist

Comment: the xml ($dir) is shown above

Comment: please `var_dump($xml->children())` and paste to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to fix

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("test.xml")
       or die("Error: Cannot create object");
//$fileList = array();


foreach($xml->children() as $Pages){
    print_r($Pages['ThumbnailPath']);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to loop over "Pages" as it already is the xml root element. So you can just omit the second loop:

```
 $xml = simplexml_load_string($string) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
 //$fileList = array();

foreach($xml->children() as $Page){
    $fileLink = $Page['ThumbnailPath'];
    echo $fileLink;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
foreach($xml->children() as $Pages){
    echo $Pages['ThumbnailPath'][0].'<br>';
}
```